# Java 2D : Creating Shape Fixtures

Tags: java, swing, shapes, java-2d

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a shape fixture in Java 2D.

More specifically, I'm trying to be able to draw a predefined shape at different locations with different colors.

I know you can use the `fill(shape)` methods to draw shapes. 
However, this seems to require creating a new shape at the coordinate that I want to draw it.

Is there any way to reuse the same shape each time? Or do I have to create a new shape for each location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by translating the transformation matrix of the graphics object.
Let's say you have a `Shape` called `shape` whose coordinates are relative to the center of the `Shape`. You also have an instance of `Graphics2D` called `g2`.
Now you code could look something like this:

```
// Set the color of the Shape.
g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
// Backup the transformation matrix so we can restore it later.
AffineTransform backupTransform = new AffineTransform(g2.getTransform());
// Translate everything that is drawn afterwards by the given coordinates.
// (This will be the new position of the center of the Shape)
g2.translate(53, 27);
// Draw the Shape.
g2.draw(shape);
// Restore the old transform, so that things drawn after this line
// are not affected by the translation.
g2.setTransform(backupTransform);
```

Comment: One up, but would you mind some formatting so that the comments can be read without scrolling?